# App Crashing when Caption isn't there

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, instagram

My app displays the Caption of the Instagram Picture and crashes every time there isn't a caption. How would I prevent that from happening? Here is the code that I am using:

```
if (entry[@"caption"][@"text"]) {
    NSString *caption = entry[@"caption"][@"text"];
    UILabel *instagramCaptionLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    [instagramCaptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:12.0]];
    [instagramCaptionLabel setText:caption];
}
```

Here is the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ed8068'`

Comment: Whenever you post a question about an error you must include the exact and complete error as well as point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the error message this means you do have a value for `@"caption"` but it happens to be an `NSNull` object.

You have two choices:

1) Don't put `NSNull` values in the dictionary.

or

2) Update your `if` statement:

```
if (entry[@"caption"] != [NSNull null] && entry[@"caption"][@"text"] != [NSNull null])
```